# Why was my question made Community Wiki?

Tags: support, specific-question, community-wiki

A [question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3164174/how-do-i-pronounce-frac52) was made Community Wiki without my permission and without so much as informing me. As I understand it, how Community Wiki posts work is that any reputation from them does not go to the original asker. This seems incredibly disingenuous for someone to have done on my behalf: I took the time to think about, formulate, ask and properly format the question, only for someone to have robbed me of the reputation from it. This doesn't seem like a clever way to run a Stack site.

Why was this decision taken and can it be reversed?

Comment: You're complaining about a robbery of..... 23 points. As the relevant moderator [commented](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3164174/how-do-i-pronounce-frac52#comment6515923_3164174), this is a highly subjective questions without an objective answer. In such a case, it makes sense for the editing thresholds to be lower. For more information, see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) explaining the process. And please consider being less dramatic.

Comment: @T.Bongers 23 points is meaningful for someone with only 136 points of rep. Also OP is not being dramatic

Comment: @Isa: Using the word "robbed" *is* being dramatic.

Answer (score 10):

You were not "robbed" of any reputation. More than just that, reputation is *not* the main point of the site. If you only ask questions on the site so you can earn points, might as well not ask questions at all.

Your question about how to pronounce 5/2 is ultimately subjective. Moreover, people are not going to vote one answer over the other *because* it's more correct or less correct, but rather because they also say it like that or not.

I originally pondered if I should close the question altogether due to its subjective nature. But it's not the first question about pronunciation, and I don't think that those are inherently off topic. But they are very subjective.

So you don't get to earn reputation on this question. If you're only interested in reputation, ask questions which are mathematical and have a mathematical answer, rather than a cultural answer.